# Why isn't my autocomplete event firing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jquery-autocomplete

I am writing an app in Rails 3.2.6 and I have the following in a view-specific CoffeeScript file called "apps.js.coffee":

```
$("#app_make").live "autocomplete", (event,ui) ->
  source: '/apps/get_makes',
  autoFocus: true,
  minLength: 2,
  select: (event, ui) ->
    #remember the selected item
    $(this).data('selected-item', ui.item.label);
    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
```

But it isn't firing. I know my selector is correct, because the following IS firing, and it's in the same script after the code above.:

```
$("#app_make").live "click", () ->
  alert("made it")
```

I am not experiencing any console errors. jQuery UI is loading successfully.

Comment: your first block of code is setting up a handler for the `autocomplete` event, not attaching an `autocomplete` to dynamically loaded objects. You could try changing it to a `click` or `focus` event and then setup your autocomplete within that event callback

Comment: I see what you mean now. But I don't know how to put the autocomplete inside a click event. I only know how to chain events to a jQuery selector. Am I supposed to do "this.autocomplete, (event, ui) ->" inside the click function? I am on shaky ground here.

Comment: I don't know coffeescript at all, but basically, yes. Set up a click event handler and inside the event do `$(this).autocomplete({});`. There is no (event, ui) because autocomplete isn't an event, it's a plugin

Comment: Error: this.autocomplete " is not a function. I have tried: this.autocomplete, $(this).autocomplete, event.autocomplete, nothing works.

Comment: I am closer now, thanks. Your description is helping me to understand what I'm doing instead of just randomly trying things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, and kudos to MrObrian for his kind help:

```
$("#app_make").live "click", ->
  $(this).autocomplete {
    source: '/apps/get_makes',
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 2,
    select: (event, ui) ->
      #remember the selected item
      $(this).data('selected-item', ui.item.label)
      $(this).val(ui.item.label)
  }
```